# Select multiple into a Symfony2 FORM

Tags: symfony

I have this scenario

`EntityA` related to `EntityB` into a **one-to-many** fashion. I have created a form for `EntityB` and I want to select (with checkboxes) some of `EntityA` element.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $id_struttura = 9;
    $channel_rates = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SestanteChannelManagerBundle:StrutturaCanaleTariffa')->findByStruttura($id_struttura);
    $list = array();
    foreach ($channel_rates as $channel_rate) {
        $list[$channel_rate->getId()] = $channel_rate->getNomeCameraTariffa();
    }
    $view = new View();
    $view->addChannelRate($channel_rates);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ViewType(), $view);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $dateRange = new DateRange($date_from, $date_to);
            $channelDisp = $this->get('channel_dispatcher');
            $inventories = $channelDisp->queryAvailabilityRates($dateRange, $channelRateList);
            return $this->render('SestanteCDTestBundle:Main:view_result.html.twig', array('inventories' => $inventories));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('SestanteCDTestBundle:Main:view.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

This is my entity

```
<?php

namespace Sestante\CDTestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class View
{
    protected $channel_rate;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->channel_rate = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @return the $date_from
     */
    public function getDateFrom() {
        return $this->date_from;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $date_to
     */
    public function getDateTo() {
        return $this->date_to;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $channel_rate
     */
    public function getChannelRate() {
        return $this->channel_rate;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $date_from
     */
    public function setDateFrom($date_from) {
        $this->date_from = $date_from;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $date_to
     */
    public function setDateTo($date_to) {
        $this->date_to = $date_to;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $channel_rate
     */
    public function addChannelRate($channel_rate) {
          $this->channel_rate[] = $channel_rate;
    }
}
```

And this is my form

```
<?php

namespace Sestante\CDTestBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ViewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date_from', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text','format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
        $builder->add('date_to', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text','format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
        $builder->add('channel_rate', 'entity', array('class'=>'SestanteChannelManagerBundle:StrutturaCanaleTariffa', 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'view';
    }
}
```

If I add a statement like this (into entity) all works good:

```
foreach ($channel_rate as $ch)
{
$this->channel_rate[] = $ch;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your form's `buildForm` method:

```
$builder->add('entitya', 'entity', array(
    'class'     => 'YourAwesomeBundle:EntityA',
    'expanded'  => true,
    'multiple'  => true
));
```

As stated in [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

EDIT looking at your code:

```
/**
 * @param field_type $channel_rate
 */
public function addChannelRate($channel_rate) {
      $this->channel_rate[] = $ch;
}
```

`$ch` is not defined in this method, you need to write `$this->channel_rate[] = $channel_rate.

Anyway, provide a `setChannelRate` method, as:

```
/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $rates
 */
public function setChannelRate($rates) {
      $this->channel_rate = $rates;
}
```

And retry.

Comment: It doesn't works. It gave me an error like "Collection expected, array given"

(sorry I can't report it because now I've choose another way that isn't the best)

Comment: Please post your entities code, and your request binding logic as well.

Comment: So I have to create a set method and iterate over my array provided into input, as I do into my last "hint" in question??

Comment: You don't need to iterate as you are replacing the whole collection - just copy/paste my method.

Comment: $rates isn't an array collection.. Is an Array, an this make a problem. So I need to iterate.. But I get what you're saying, so I was on the right way.... ;-)